# How to install b43-firmware on arch without internet access?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, packaging

I currently don't have wire internet access in the PC I'm trying to install arch to, but my other PC (win7) can access the internet just fine. I tried downloading the [b43 package from the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware/) and copy it with a pendrive but when I run `makepkg -s --asroot` it goes and tries to download the source from "http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2" which doesn't work since I still don't have internet access.

I manually downloaded the source on my other pc but I guess I have to modify the PKGBUILD file to reflect this so instead of trying to fetch it online it looks in my local folder? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the file to the same dir as PKGBUILD and then add its filename to the `source` array.

Otherwise I'd suggest you just look at the build procedure in the PKGBUILD file and then build it manually. After you get internet access, you can simply reinstall it to get the package tracked.

Comment: That's what I did, for some reason adding the filename to the source array threw me some errors but manually building it following the `PKGBUILD` file did the trick thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another Arch system?
If not - then it's better to install Arch as Virtual Machine (VirtualBox,VMWare,etc.) before going on your real PC, it'll make you more familiar with the installation process.

In your existing Arch machine, go to the directory of the AUR package, and run `makepkg -s` (by the way, it's recommended not to use `--asroot`).

This should create a file named something like `b43-firmware-5.100.138-2-any.pkg.tar`
Just transfer the .pkg.tar file to the new installation, and run `pacman -U b43-firmware-5.100.138-2-any.pkg.tar`